# How to write a program that is generating a list of operational signs that have an arithmetical meaning with a given number?

Tags: prolog

I need to write a progam which is getting arguments:

- `list_of_numbers`,
- `result_number`,
- `Result_list` (for generating list of signs).

And is generating a list of operation sings `+` and `-` that in arithmetical meaning have a result of `result_number`. Also, it does concatenation of numbers to make new ones so the arithmetical meaning would be right.

So, for example, if we have a method `arrange_signs(list_of_numbers, result_number, Result_List)`, here's how it would work:

```
?- arrange_signs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4, Result_List).
12-3+45-67+8-9 = 4

?- arrange_signs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 15, Result_List).
1+2-34+56+7-8-9 = 15
```

How to write a program which is doing that?

I've written a program which is doing this:

```
?- arrange_signs([12, 3, 45, 67, 8, 9], 4, Result_List).
12-3+45-67+8-9 = 4

?- arrange_signs([1, 2, 34, 56, 7, 8, 9], 15, Result_List).
1+2-34+56+7-8-9 = 15
```

But I'm not sure how to write a program that is working with `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.

Here's my code:

```
arrange_signs([Number|Number_List],Result,Result_List) :- 
    generateOperationList(Number_List, [], OperationList),
    find_result(Number,Number_List,OperationList,Result), 
    getResult([Number|Number_List], OperationList, Result_List), 
    show_result(Result_List, Result). 

generateOperationList([_Head|Tail], Temp_List, [First_Operation|OperationList]) :- 
    getSign(First_Operation),
    generateOperationList(Tail, Temp_List, OperationList). 

generateOperationList([],Temp_List,Temp_List).

getSign('-').
getSign('+').

getOperation(Number1, '-', Number2, Answer) :- 
    Answer is Number1 - Number2.

getOperation(Number1, '+', Number2, Answer) :- 
    Answer is Number1 + Number2.

getResult([Number|Number_List], [Operation|OperationList], [Number,Operation|Result_List]) :- 
    getResult(Number_List, OperationList, Result_List).

getResult(Number_List, [], Number_List).

find_result(Temp_Answer,[Number|Number_List],[Operation|OperationList],Result) :- 
    getOperation(Temp_Answer, Operation, Number, New_Temp_Result),
    find_result(New_Temp_Result,Number_List,OperationList,Result).

find_result(New_Temp_Result,[],[],New_Temp_Result). 

print_result(Ready_Result) :- 
    write(Ready_Result).

show_result([First_Element|Result_List],Result) :- 
    generate_result([First_Element|Result_List],Result,'',Ready_Result),
    print_result(Ready_Result).

generate_result([First_Element|Result_List],Result,Formatting_Result,Ready_Result) :- 
    atom_concat(Formatting_Result, First_Element, New_Formatting_Result), 
    generate_result(Result_List,Result,New_Formatting_Result,Ready_Result).

generate_result([],Result,Formatting_Result,Ready_Result) :- 
    atom_concat(Formatting_Result, '=', Temp_Variable),
    atom_concat(Temp_Variable, Result, New_Formatting_Result), 
    generate_result(New_Formatting_Result,Ready_Result).

generate_result(New_Formatting_Result,New_Formatting_Result).
```

Comment: Your examples look like they do more than just "arrange signs". it also allows concatenation of numbers to make new ones? *E.g.*, `6, 7, 8` might lead to `67 + 8`?

Comment: Yes, they also allow concatenation of numbers to make new ones. Just like you showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but I find difficult to understand your code.

I propose the following solution

```
atomL_concat([], '').

atomL_concat([A | T], C1) :-
  atomL_concat(T, C0),
  atom_concat(A, C0, C1).

arrangeS([], Target, Target, [' = ', ATarget]) :-
  number_atom(Target, ATarget).

arrangeS([NH | NT], Target, Sum0, ['+', ANH | ST]) :-
  Sum1 is Sum0 + NH,
  arrangeS(NT, Target, Sum1, ST),
  number_atom(NH, ANH).

arrangeS([NH | NT], Target, Sum0, ['-', ANH | ST]) :-
  Sum1 is Sum0 - NH,
  arrangeS(NT, Target, Sum1, ST),
  number_atom(NH, ANH).

arrangeS([NH1, NH2 | NT], Target, Sum, ResList) :-
  NH is NH1 * 10 + NH2,
  arrangeS([NH | NT], Target, Sum, ResList).

arrange_signs(NumList, Target, ResList) :- 
  arrangeS(NumList, Target, 0, ['+'|ResList]),
  atomL_concat(ResList, PrintList),
  write(PrintList), nl.
```

If you want accept solutions starting with a negative number (by example: "-12-3-4+5-6+7+8+9 = 4") you can remove the first `+` removal and write `arrange_signs/2` as

```
arrange_signs(NumList, Target, ResList) :- 
  arrangeS(NumList, Target, 0, ResList),
  atomL_concat(ResList, PrintList),
  write(PrintList), nl.
```

but, in this case, the solutions starting with a positive number are preceded by a `+` sign (so "+1+2-34+5+6+7+8+9 = 4" instead of "1+2-34+5+6+7+8+9 = 4").